# WPF TextBox control filter + validation

Tags: wpf

I have TextBox bound to a text property in my window with a validation rule (length is = 4).  I needed to add filtering so I took ThomasLebruns WPFDeveloperTools FilteredTextBox.  That works but when I use the control I specify each time the Validation.ErrorTemplate and the Binding.ValidationRules - I want to build those into the FilteredTextBox control so they apply automatically to every FilteredTextBox - how to manage that?
Currently I have to:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <ps:FilteredTextBox x:Name="textboxPanId" Type="Hex" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="35" Margin="0,2,0,2" MaxLength="4"
                        Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}">
      <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="pan_id" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ps:PanIdValidation />
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
      </TextBox.Text>
    </ps:FilteredTextBox>
```

I would like just:

```
<ps:FilteredTextBox x:Name="textboxPanId" Type="Hex" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="35" Margin="0,2,0,2" MaxLength="4">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="pan_id" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
  </TextBox.Text>
```

but have the error template and validation rule applied.  How to move the setting of the Validation.ErrorTemplate and Binding.ValidationRule into resource dictionary with rest of FilteredTextBox xaml?.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
    ...
  </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create a style for FilteredTextBox in your ResourceDictionary you can set these there, but at least the ErrorTemplate for almost sure.

Comment: Yes you're right a '<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">' in style block does it for the error template.  But how to manage the ValidationRule binding?

Comment: Hmm, since that's nested inside the Binding which you set on the control instance I'm not sure if you can do it in XAML. Can't you set PanIdValidation as a default in code so that you only have to explicitly specify it if it's something different?